# Combinatorics - Coloring a 3x3 chess with a restriction.

Tags: combinatorics

Let's imagine a 3x3 chess with 9 elements and every element can be colored with red and blue paints.We have a restriction, that we must have at least 1 square 2x2 painted red.How many ways we have?

Its hard to explain what I did but I found 99 ways and Ι would like to check if it is right or wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inclusion-exclusion gets 95.

For each $2\times2$ square, there are 32, that's 128.

Subtract the ones with two $2\times2$ squares. If the squares overlap in two cells, there are 8 ways to color the remaining cells, so $4\times8=32$. If the squares overlap in one cell, then 4 ways to color the remaining cells, so $2\times4=8$. Total $32+8=40$ to subtract from the $128$, leaving 88.

The ones with three red $2\times2$ squares can be completed in 2 ways, so $4\times2=8$ of these. Add that back in to get $88+8=96$.

Finally, four red $2\times2$ squares, just 1 way, subtract it out, you get $96-1=95$, done.

Comment: I counted two times something. I found my mistake.Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

With this PARI/GP-program, I get $95$ possibilities.

```
? z=0;for(n=0,511,w=binary(n);for(j=1,9-length(w),w=concat(0,w));gef=0;if(w[1]*w
[2]*w[4]*w[5]==1,gef=1);if(w[2]*w[3]*w[5]*w[6]==1,gef=1);if(w[4]*w[5]*w[7]*w[8]=
=1,gef=1);if(w[5]*w[6]*w[8]*w[9]==1,gef=1);if(gef==1,z=z+1));print(z)
95
```

I numbered the squares in the usual way

```
  1 2 3
  4 5 6
  7 8 9
```

and every combination with $1's$ in at least one of the squares

$1-2-4-5$

$2-3-5-6$

$4-5-7-8$

$5-6-8-9$

was accepted. Did I miss anything ?

Comment: No ,your answer it's ok and I like your kind of solution. I counted two times something in my solution.Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using principle of inclusion and exclusion.
first count the number of colorings when there is a red square ate the upper left corner. that is  $2^5$. considering four possible corners you get $4*2^5=128$ colorings.
But coloring with 2 red squares are over counted. counting those in the similar way you get $4*2^3+2*2^2=40$ colorings.
again colorings with 3 squares are under counted. going on like this. You get
$128-40+8-1=95$ colorings with at least $1$ square.